# Unable to connect in docker an empty 7.0 .net core api

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I created an empty project from the ASP.NET Core Web API template with swagger. If I run it on HTTP it works perfect, however, when I run it with docker it is not able to find the webpage

The ports 80 and 443 are exposed, I let visual studio run the docker image, and it is mapping the ports correctly

[image]

Url to enter: https://localhost:49163/swagger

The container is listening to the correct ports,
Container log:

```html
2023-01-10 11:17:40 info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
2023-01-10 11:17:40       Now listening on: https://[::]:443
2023-01-10 11:17:40 info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
2023-01-10 11:17:40       Now listening on: http://[::]:80
2023-01-10 11:17:40 info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
2023-01-10 11:17:40       Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
2023-01-10 11:17:40 info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
2023-01-10 11:17:40       Hosting environment: Development
2023-01-10 11:17:40 info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
2023-01-10 11:17:40       Content root path: /app
```

Docker file

```html
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Test.csproj", "."]
RUN dotnet restore "./Test.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "Test.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Test.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Test.dll"]
```

Comment: generally swagger is not enabled in production env. try to access another endpoint. or enable swagger in production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, it seems like the docker couldn't map my network adapters correctly. So after disabling all the networks adapters and only letting the main one. I reinstalled docker and it was working correctly